# in pdfmake how to print html data from a string

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdfmake

This is the html string and i want to print it in pdfmake

```
let html_string = "<html><head></head><body><p>HI</p></body></html>";

        //something like this
        { text: html_string,    

            pageBreak: 'after',
          },
```

it should print as a html content in a part of pdfmake: how to print string containing html as it is in pdf .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a html parser to get the html content you want.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

After that, i would write an object build function to get the correct html tag content you're looking for.

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';


const root = parse('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>');
   var htmlBody = root.querySelector('#list');
function getContentBuilder (htmlBody ) {

  var record = {}
  //Locate htmlBody childnode that you want and insert to record
  return record;

}
    //something like this
    { text: getContentBuilder(htmlBody) ,    

        pageBreak: 'after',
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. Convert the html to string before passing it to pdfmake. You can use [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text)
.

```js
const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text');

let dd = {
    pageSize: "A4",
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    content: [
        {
            text: htmlToText.fromString("<p>Hello <strong>World</strong></p>", {
              wordwrap: 130
            }),
            style: "",
          }
    ],
}
let printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
```

Option 2. Use [html-to-pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdfmake)
. You will have to add jsdom if you are doing it in Nodejs side.

```js
const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");
let jsdom = require("jsdom");
let { JSDOM } = jsdom;
let { window } = new JSDOM("");
const htmlToPdfmake = require("html-to-pdfmake");

let dd = {
    pageSize: "A4",
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    content: [
        {
            text: htmlToPdfmake(salesConditions.salesConditionBody, {
              window: window,
            }),
            style: "",
          }
    ],
}
let printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML2PDF Js library to make pdf from html string.

check this link [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf)

many JS libraies available in npm to create PDF from image or html.

Comment: i am already using Pdfmake . so some contents are for example (rich text) are in html format .To bring that content as it is in pdf

Comment: Im also facing the same problem, I have used pdfmake now I want to print html string as it is on the pdf, how can I do that. html string contains table, if not table atleast in column wise structure I should be able to do it. Is their any way to do it using pdfmake.